# Talend multiple build jobs

Tags: talend

We are using open source Talend studio and we have more then 50 jobs.
Each build generate zip file contains  all it's artifacts ( .bat .sh context, jar files)

Is there a way  to generate multiple build process from the studio or command line ( Talend open source tool )

Comment: Doesn't it work by selecting all your jobs > build Job or is it that you want separate zip files?

Comment: multiple zip files ( one for each job). i don"t want to build it one by one.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with Open Studio. There is a command line tool but unfortunately only available in enterprise version.

Comment: It possible, but which version you use plz ?

Comment: "Talend Open Studio for Data Integration"
Version: 5.6.1
Build id: V5.6.1_20141207_1530

Answer (score 2):

In the "build job" window, there is a double arrow in the left,

[image]

Click on it, and you get the job tree, select all jobs or what you want, and you will get a single zip file containing all your jobs each one in a separate folder.

Comment: I understood that Arnon wants separate zip files

Comment: Thanks  that will solve the first  part , one more thing  is  it possible  to add the java files to  Git  and build it from Jenkinse.( i found  some question with the same problem  but  no solution)

Comment: @ArnonRodman it solve the written question, you can edit your post and add other parts. So after the building you can create a script that push into Git, for jenkins i never worked on it.

Comment: @ArnonRodman same for me, the only answer is the command line tool available in enterprise only. I started to think about developing this tool based on the sources of Talend Open Studio, but not sure if it is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Not an ideal solution but you can use a small script to split the whole zip into separate job zips:

```
ZIP=test.zip # path to your all-in-one zip file
ROOT=$(basename $ZIP .zip)
DEST=./dest
rm -rf $DEST # be careful with this one!
mkdir -p $DEST
unzip $ZIP
find $ROOT -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name lib|while read JOBPATH
do
        JOB=$(basename $JOBPATH)
        echo "job: $JOB"
        DJOB="$DEST/$JOB"
        mkdir -p "$DJOB"
        cp -R "$JOBPATH" "$DJOB/$JOB"
        cp $ROOT/jobInfo.properties $DJOB # here you should replace job=<proper job name> and jobId, but not sure you really need it
        mkdir -p "$DJOB/lib"
        RUNFILE="${JOBPATH}/${JOB}_run.sh"
        LIBS=$(grep "^java" "$RUNFILE"|cut -d' ' -f 5)
        IFS=':' read -ra ALIB <<< "$LIBS"
        for LIB in "${ALIB[@]}"; do
                if [ "$LIB" = "." -o "$LIB" = "\$ROOT_PATH" ]; then continue; fi
                echo "$LIB"
        done|grep "\$ROOT_PATH/../lib"|cut -b 19-|while read DEP
        do
                cp "$ROOT/lib/$DEP" "$DJOB/lib/"
        done
        (cd $DJOB ; zip -r -m ../$JOB.zip .)
        rmdir $DJOB
done
```

Comment: This  was  helpful, Thx